# VBA EXCEL - Assigning a name to an object

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on developing a chart for time planning and within I have a line that is placed on the current week. I am trying to assign a name to it so that I can delete it when i reset the spreadsheet. I cannot just delete all shapes because i have buttons that I need to keep on the sheet so I thought id assign a Name to the shape to then just delete this shape only in my "Reset" function however i get an error when i try to assign the name to it. Here is the function that draws the line and then sets it as an object, any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Public Function DrawCurrentDateLine()

    Dim wsCRC As Worksheet
    Set wsCRC = Worksheets("CRC")

    Dim lrowcrc As Long
    lrowcrc = CRC.LastRowInCRC

    Dim CurrentDateColumn As Long
    CurrentDateColumn = GetTodaysDateColumn()

    Dim x1 As Long, x2 As Long, y1 As Long, y2 As Long

    x1 = Cells(8, CurrentDateColumn).Left
    x2 = Cells(lrowcrc, CurrentDateColumn).Left
    y1 = Cells(8, CurrentDateColumn).Top
    y2 = Cells(lrowcrc + 1, CurrentDateColumn).Top

    Debug.Print lrowcrc     'Returns 91
    Debug.Print CurrentDateColumn       'Returns 89
    Dim CurrentDateLine As Object

    Set CurrentDateLine = wsCRC.Shapes.AddLine(x1, y1, x2, y2).Line.ForeColor
    CurrentDateLine.Name = "Current Date Line"

    With CurrentDateLine
        .RGB = RGB(30, 30, 30)
        '.Weight = 3
    End With


End Function
```

The Error i get is at the `CurrentDateLine.Name = "Current Date Line"` line which tells me that the "object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: A quick look, and I see that you are trying to change the name of `ForeColor` instead of the shape itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because CurrentDateLine is being set to the ForeColor.  I believe what you want is the following:

```
Set CurrentDateLine = wsCRC.Shapes.AddLine(x1, y1, x2, y2)
CurrentDateLine.Name = "Current Date Line"
```

Comment: Ah, i see, quite new to vba so making alot of silly errors. Thanks for your help!